# Trying to pass/fetch data for stripe api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, marketplace

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails and I have been following this [tutorial](https://github.com/justalever/back-my-idea) on how to implement an online marketplace by using Stripe's Connect API. This tutorial guides you on how to make single item purchases, I have tried to advance myself past this tutorial and create a marketplace where a user can purchase multiple items and put them in a basket and checkout, a nice challenge as the tutorial is focused on one item. However, I am stuck on the checkout `_form.html.erb`.

Before, to fetch the `publishable_key`,

```
<%= form_with model: current_user, local: true, url: subscription_url, method: :post, html: { id: "payment-form", class: "stripe-form" }, **data: { stripe_key: product.user.publishable_key }**  do |form| %>
```

but now because I am submitting a cart full of products instead of one single item the `data: { stripe_key: }` is now dysfunctional. Instead, I thought it might be a good idea to do `data: { stripe_key: @account.publishable_key }` to fetch the `publishable_key` from the database but it is not working.

I am most likely forgetting something important. Any help would be sound!

http://localhost:3000/subscription/new?account=4&amount=17

**The Error**

```
NoMethodError in Subscriptions#new
Showing /Users/kaneandrewgibson/Desktop/Charlie/WOP/app/views/subscriptions/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `publishable_key' for nil:NilClass
```

***`Subscriptions/_form.html.erb`***

```rb
<%= form_with model: current_user, local: true, url: subscription_url, method: :post, html: { id: "payment-form", class: "stripe-form" }, data: { stripe_key: @account.publishable_key }  do |form| %>
  <div>
    <label for="card-element" class="label">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>

    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert" class="text-sm text-red-400"></div>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="account" value="<%= params[:account] %>">

  <button>Back <%= number_to_currency(params[:amount]) %> /mo toward <em><%= %></em></button>
<% end %>
```

**`SubscriptionsController`**

```rb
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @account = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  # Reference:
  # https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions
  def create
    @account = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    key = @account.user.access_code
    Stripe.api_key = key

    plan_id = params[:plan]
    plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)
    token = params[:stripeToken]


    customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
                Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
              else
                Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email, source: token)
              end

              Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
                customer: customer,
                amount: @cart.total_price * 100,
                confirm: true,
                currency: 'gbp',
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                application_fee_percent: 3,
              }, {
                stripe_account: 'key',
              })


    options = {
      stripe_id: customer.id,
      subscribed: true,
    }

    options.merge!(
      card_last4: params[:user][:card_last4],
      card_exp_month: params[:user][:card_exp_month],
      card_exp_year: params[:user][:card_exp_year],
      card_type: params[:user][:card_brand]
    )

    current_user.perk_subscriptions << plan_id
    current_user.update(options)

    # Update project attributes
    project_updates = {
      backings_count: @project.backings_count.next,
      current_donation_amount: @project.current_donation_amount + (plan.amount/100).to_i,
    }
    @project.update(project_updates)


    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription was setup successfully!"
  end

  def destroy
    subscription_to_remove = params[:id]
    plan_to_remove = params[:plan_id]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(subscription_to_remove).delete
    current_user.subscribed = false
    current_user.perk_subscriptions.delete(plan_to_remove)
    current_user.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription has been cancelled."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kane.

It looks like your account ID isn't getting into your controller. I would expect the URL to look something like this (`account_id` instead of `account`):

`http://localhost:3000/subscription/new?account_id=4&amount=17`

And I would expect the `SubscriptionsController#new` to be looking in the `Account` model rather than the `User` model, and to be using the same `account_id` param:

```rb
@account = Account.find_by_id(params[:account_id])
```

Comment: @KaneAndrewGibson, if my answer helped fix your problem, please go ahead and accept the answer to let other know that this helped. If the problem was something else, please add your own answer detailing what was done, then accept your answer. This really helps the community see what solved your problem.